# Post to fan page as application not as user (but the page is not showing on /me/accounts)

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm trying to post to a page as an application using C# Facebook SDK, I've browsed through lots of posts explaining how to do so and I think I understood how, the only problem is that when I access /me/accounts/ it just shows applications I have made, it doesn't show any page I'm an administrator, is there anything I need to do besides being an administrator to have the page I want to post to listed on /me/accounts/ ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Post 'as an application' isn't a feature of the API - and for the pages not being present in the `/accounts` connection - check your user access token has the `manage_pages` permission granted - read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/

Comment: thank you Igy, the token I was trying to use wasn't generated with the "manage_accounts" permission, I created another token with the permission you said and now I can see the pages I'm registered as an administrator